# get field from json and assign to variable in bash script?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a json store in jsonFile

```
{
  "key1": "aaaa bbbbb",
  "key2": "cccc ddddd"
}
```

I have code in `mycode.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
value=($(jq -r '.key1' jsonFile))
echo "$value"
```

After I run `./mycode.sh` the result is `aaaa`
but if I just run `jq -r '.key1' jsonFile` the result is `aaaa bbbbb`

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

With that line of code

```
value=($(jq -r '.key1' jsonFile))
```

you are assigning both values to an [array](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays). Note the outer parantheses `()` around the command.
Thus you can access the values individually or echo the content of the entire array.

```
$ echo "${value[@]}"
aaaa bbbb

$ echo "${value[0]}"
aaaa

$ echo "${value[1]}"
bbbb
```

Since you echoed `$value` without specifying which value you want to get you only get the first value of the array.

Comment: i tried your solution and it works on the command line. however, when I put the same code in a bash script i keep getting **syntax error near unexpected token `(**. any idea why this happens ?

Comment: actually i solved mine :) my problem was i had spaces " " around equal sign "=" when i assign output to variable. I had sth like x = $(script). After I removed the spaces it works fine! Thanks :)

Comment: Nice. Have a look over there for a superb reference: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters

Comment: what if I want to save "aaaa bbbbb" into bash array as one element? like ("aaaa bbbbb"). I have same problem with parsing json and save two key values into array.
`echo '{ "foo": "foovalue1 foovalue2", "bar": "barvalue" }'`
output: 
"foovalue1 foovalue2"
"barvalue"
I want to save it to bash array as two (not three!) elements, like:
`array=($(echo '{ "foo": "foovalue1 foovalue2", "bar": "barvalue" }' | jq -r '.foo, .bar'))`

Answer (score 10):

```
local result=$(<your_json_response>)
local aws_access_key=$(jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId' <<< ${result})
local aws_secret_key=$(jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey' <<< ${result})
local session_token=$(jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken' <<< ${result})
```

Above code is another way to get the values from json response.

Comment: Lol. I literally came here trying to figure out how to do this for my AWS creds.