# JQ how to combine heterogeneous objects into one array?

Tags: jq

How could I use JQ to parse the following JSON object and produce the output below?

JSON Input:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "a": "A"
    },
    "key2": {
        "b": "123"
    },
    "key3": {
        "c": ["C1", "C2"]
    }
}
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  "a": "A",
  "b": 123,
  "c": "C1",
  "c": "C2"
]
```

Comment: Both your input and o/p is not valid. Check it out at json lint https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Sorry, updated the input. Does the output necessarily need to be in JSON format? I'd like to generate an array if possible through JQ and then iterate through it in my bash script.

Comment: jq cannot produce such an expected output. You need an array of objects

Comment: Although @Inian's claim that jq cannot produce the output you say you want is not literally true, it is doubtful that the format you are asking for is going to be very useful. Since you mention you want output suitable for use in a bash script, why not tell us more about what the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program produces the output shown below it:

```
def q: "\"\(.)\"";

.[]
| to_entries[]
| (.key|q) as $k
| if .value|type == "array"
  then .value[] | "\($k): \(q)"
  else "\($k): \(.value|q)"
  end
```

Output:

```
"a": "A"
"b": "123"
"c": "C1"
"c": "C2"
```

This, or something very much like it, should be sufficient for using in a bash script, but if you really want the format shown in the Q, feel free to fiddle around.  A more useful way to spend your time would probably be to read up on jq-bash interoperability, e.g. here on SO:

- [Is there a way to output jq into multiple variables for bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030229/is-there-a-way-to-output-jq-into-multiple-variables-for-bash-script)
- [get field from json and assign to variable in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528142/get-field-from-json-and-assign-to-variable-in-bash-script)

... and many others.